# Displaying a string backward

Tags: java, string

Good day! I have here a Java program that should display a string backward. For example, "ketchup" should display "puhctek".

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StringManipulation {

    public static String ReverseStr(String S) {
           String newS = "";
           for (int i=0; i<S.length(); i++) {
              newS = S.charAt(i) + newS;
           }
           return newS;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        String menu, choiceStr = "", enterString="", noSpace;

        do {    
            menu = "MENU \n" +
                    "(1) Enter a string \n" +
                    "(2) Remove all spaces from a string \n" +
                    "(3) Display the string backward \n" +
                    "(4) Quit";
            choiceStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menu);
            choice = Integer.parseInt(choiceStr);
            switch (choice) {
                case 1: enterString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the string:"); 
                        break;
                case 2: noSpace = enterString.replaceAll("\\s", "");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, noSpace); 
                        break;
                case 3: ReverseStr(enterString);
                        break;
                case 4: System.exit(0);
            }
        } while (choice != 4);
    }

}
```

It works well when it enters a string, removes the spaces of a string, but when displaying the string backward, the dialog box returns to the menu. Please help me what is wrong in the code. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello @userunknown! I mean the InputDialog in Java I'm sorry.

Comment: @FirstLady: See Berry120's answer: Case 3 doesn't have an InputDialog. Btw.: What input should be displayed with such a dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go dude:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        String menu, choiceStr = "", enterString = "", noSpace;
        String stringWithNoSpaces = "";
        String reversedString = "";

        do {
            menu = "MENU \n"
                    + "(1) Enter a string \n"
                    + "(2) Remove all spaces from a string \n"
                    + "(3) Display the string backward \n"
                    + "(4) Quit";
            choiceStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menu);
            choice = Integer.parseInt(choiceStr);
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    enterString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the string:");
                    stringWithNoSpaces = enterString;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    stringWithNoSpaces = enterString.replaceAll("\\s", "");                    
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, stringWithNoSpaces);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    reversedString = ReverseStr(stringWithNoSpaces);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, reversedString);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        } while (choice != 4);
    }
```

I made a few changes: Your option 3 returned to the menu because your ReverseStr method returned a reversed string, but you never caught it and displayed it. You were probably just in a hurry lol. I made one other change, I could be wrong about this but when you want to reverse a string, it would not send it the string with spaces removed (suggesting you chose option 2 before option 3). I have made it so that if you choose option 2 before option 3, it will reverse the string that no longer has spaces. Enjoy!

Comment: Hello Captain! I appreciate your help so much! Thank you for making some revisions haha I'm so thankful!

Answer (score 3):

```
case 3: ReverseStr(enterString);
    break;
```

All you're doing here is calling the ReverseStr method then breaking out - you're not doing anything with the result, such as displaying it to the user. You probably want something like:

```
case 3: String rev = ReverseStr(enterString);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rev); 
    break;
```

As a side note, the following is a much easier, quicker 1 liner for reversing a string in Java:

```
new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
```